# Integrating Mesonet algorithm with a webUI for deepfake detection model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, deep-fake

There is a algorithm in github named Mesonet. this could detect deepfake images. Do anyone have an idea in integrating this algorithm with my webUI like this "https://aravindhprabu2005.github.io/Deepfake-Detector/"?  This is my UI for the deepfake detection.

The github link for mesonet algorithm is "https://github.com/DariusAf/MesoNet". I don't have an idea to integrate the UI with this algorithm. Could anybody give me the steps to integrate it. I need a proper guidance for integrating it.